# AWS CloudFront: generate template for existing resourse

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I manually created a CF distribution with a bunch of sophisticated behaviors and Lambda functions. Now I need to automate the deployment and create this CloudFront distribution as a part of CI/CD pipeline.
Is there any way to generate a template (basically a yaml file) based on existing resource? Should I use CloudFormer?

Cheers

Comment: I guess only CloudFormer on AWS, except there are any 3rd applications. But you are using CICD's terms, it means you should make your infra become immutable. So, you should continuous on your current CF template, just create another CF template for your new component (like `cloudfront`). Take a look at `nested CF Template`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Taking a look on a nested CF now. In terms of CICDs my infra will be immutable most of the time but it's possible that devs will tweak CF template a bit. That's why I must include it to the pipeline.

Comment: I'm working on CICD system too. I think if you re-disign your current CF template with `nested style`, separate to many CF templates for each layer, services as needed, you will easier to maintenance CF templates.